# MessageEndevent on Flowable

Tags: bpmn, flowable

Is something like MessageEndevent available on Flowable?[attached is the screenshot from  FlowFest'19 - the annual community event where I see something like 'Message end event' after the event 'Send Mail'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RXsWz.png)

I am not sure what that symbol/event means and I could not find it in the official documentation. It wasn't available in the list of events while using Flowable enterprise or Opensource version. What does that event(in the screenshot attached) mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, on this screenshot there is a message end event. However, this is a presentation which includes a symbolic BPMN process. Currently, there is no support for a message end event in Flowable.

The best to achieve the same behavior is to use the [Send Event Task](https://documentation.flowable.com/latest/model/bpmn/reference/send-event-task) directly before an [End Event](https://documentation.flowable.com/latest/model/bpmn/reference/end-event). This is a bit more verbose in the diagram, but does the same job.